# Issue with click function and .clone()

Tags: jquery

I have a bit of a strange problem. I am cloning a hidden element and appending it to a div created by jquery. It works fine, but not when I click on any of the child elements of the div (which is basically an image and some text. If I click on any of the child elements it animates up to the point when the cloning happens, then stops. Anywhere outside these elements, within the .over div, and it's fine. The html for my clickable div is:

```
<li class="infobox">
   <a href="#"><img class="thumb" src="img/10.jpg" alt="image10" /></a>
   <div class="over">
   <img src="img/search_icon.png" alt="read more" />
   <h6>New business</h6>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
   </div>
 </li>
```

My jquery code is:

```
$('#news_gallery li').click(function(event) {

    var index = newsover.index($(this)); //cycle through read more links
    var offset = $(this).offset();  //Get the thumb position to animate from
    var animFinished = false;  //Create boolean to check when ani finishes

    $('#news-articles .news-article').hide().eq(index).show(); // show the article for the corresponding link and hide the others

    var article = $('#news-articles .news-article').eq(index);


    // Create the expanded item container
    var expandedItem = $('<div>', {
        id: 'item-expanded',
        css: {
            width: DDBR.constant.ITEM_WIDTH,
            height: DDBR.constant.ITEM_HEIGHT,
            background: '#fff',
            position: 'absolute',
            zIndex: 999
            },  
        });         

    // Get the current item offset to animate from
    expandedItem.css({
        top: offset.top,
        left: offset.left,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        opacity: 0
        });

    $('body').append(expandedItem);  //Add the shaded overlay and the expanded item to the body

    //Animate the size of the expanded item
    expandedItem.animate({
        width: DDBR.constant.ITEM_EXPANDED_WIDTH,
        height: DDBR.constant.ITEM_EXPANDED_HEIGHT,
        left: $(window).scrollLeft() + $(window).width()/2,
        top: $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()/2,
        marginTop: -DDBR.constant.ITEM_EXPANDED_HEIGHT/2,
        marginLeft: -DDBR.constant.ITEM_EXPANDED_WIDTH/2,
        opacity: 1
        }, {
            duration: DDBR.constant.ITEM_ANIMATION_SPEED,
            easing: DDBR.constant.ITEM_ANIMATION_EASING,
            queue: false,
            complete: function() {
                animFinished = true;
                if (animFinished) {
                    expandFurther();                            
                    }
                }
            }); 


    var articleClone = article.clone();  // clone the article for the corresponding link
    var articleHeight = article.actual('outerHeight'); //Get the height of the hidden div

    //expand the box further from the center
    expandFurther = function() {
        expandedItem.animate({
            width: 875,
            height: articleHeight,
            marginTop: -articleHeight/2,
            marginLeft: -875/2
            }, {
                duration: DDBR.constant.ITEM_ANIMATION_SPEED,
                easing: DDBR.constant.ITEM_ANIMATION_EASING,
                queue: false,
                complete: function() {
                    animFinished = true;
                    if (animFinished) {
                    loadContent();
                    }
                }
            })              
        }; //END expandFurther function

    loadContent = function() {
        animFinished = false;       
        expandedItem.append(articleClone);  //Add the cloned image to the expanded item container
        }; //END loadContent function

}); //END click function
```

Sorry for the quite extensive code. Like I said, it works fine as long as I click anywhere elese within the parent div, but not when I click on the child elements within the div.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
var articleClone = article.clone();
```

use

```
 var articleClone = article.clone(true);
```

this will copy events attached to element and your issue should be resolved.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/b6eYg/)

From the docs

> .clone( [withDataAndEvents] )
>
> withDataAndEvents
>
>  A Boolean indicating
>   whether event handlers should be copied along with the elements. As of
>   jQuery 1.4, element data will be copied as well.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately it didn't solve the issue. The issue seems to be with the cloning itself when a child element of the '.over' class is clicked. Not when clicking on any element of the cloned item itself.